# Django's HttpResponseRedirect seems to strip off my subdomain?

Tags: django, django-urls

Whenever my django site calls "HttpResponseRedirect" in a view object to redirect to another url it strips off the sub-domain and goes back to the main site.  I'm working off of the SVN branch of Django.  Here is the example:

```
#Request comes in as https://sub1.mydomain.com
def view(request):
  return HttpResponseRedirect("/test_url") #The browser will actually get redirected to https://mydomain.com/test_url
```

Is there a reason this is done?  Should I have to redirect to the full path including the sub-domain?

Answer (score 4):

Django has some methods it always applies to a response. One of these is `django.http.utils.fix_location_header`. This ensures that a redirection response always contains an absolute URI (as required by HTTP spec).

This method uses `request.build_absolute_uri`, which in-turn uses `request.get_host`. `get_host` tries to get the `HTTP_HOST` from `request.META`, falling back to using `SERVER_NAME`.

My guess is that your server isn't providing the `HTTP_HOST` and that your `SERVER_NAME` is set to `mydomain.com`.

Hopefully now you know what you're looking for, you can run some tests to see what's going wrong.

Comment: FYI, this answer is also useful for troubleshooting "why is Django sometimes redirecting from https to http?" (e.g., after a login form). If your server or reverse proxy isn't providing Django an accurate `request.is_secure`, then `fix_location_header` will get the scheme wrong when it makes a redirect absolute.

Comment: @medmunds I have exactly this problem, django redirects from https to http on making redirect from relative url. What kind of http headers should server/proxy exactly set to solve the problem?

Comment: @thedk it'll be something like X-Forwarded-Proto or X-Forwarded-SSL -- and you'll need to tell Django to pay attention to it. Take a look at SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header (and take the security warning seriously). Also, searching for "django request.is_secure" will turn up some other, pre-1.4 solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The HttpResponseRedirect will simply return a 302 status code with the Location header set. The url resolver won't take the subdomain into consideration ( see http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8896 ). Your best bet it to either reconstruct it from scratch (HTTP_HOST on META) or just use the Middleware from http://thingsilearned.com/2009/01/05/using-subdomains-in-django/ .

Cheers