# Django keeps changing URL from http://localhost/ to http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Tags: python, django, django-forms, nginx

As the title described, Django keeps changing my URL from `/localhost/` to `/127.0.0.1:8080/` which keeps messing up my serving static files by Nginx. Any ideas why its doing this? Thanks!

/*********EDIT*********/
Here is the Nginx configuration:

```
server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm)$
    {
            root   /srv/www/testing;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
    }

    location /doc {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /images {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
    }
```

Here is Apache config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerName testing
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/testing

    <Directory /srv/www/testing>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/www/testing/apache/django.wsgi

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: how are you building your URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edit2:**

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

What I think is happening is when you use your `httpresponseredirect`, the `HTTP_HOST` header is giving it the `127.0.0.1:8080`, because of your `proxy_pass` setting.

[Django's HttpResponseRedirect seems to strip off my subdomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457006/djangos-httpresponseredirect-seems-to-strip-off-my-subdomain)

> Django has some methods it always
>   applies to a response. One of these is
>   django.utils.http.fix_location_header.
>   This ensures that a redirection
>   response always contains an absolute
>   URI (as required by HTTP spec).

Comment: No. Im using relative URLs in all my links and forms. I am using Nginx to forward all requests (except static files) onto Apache which is 127.0.0.1:8080. I know 127.0.0.1 is same as localhost, and even if I use just 127.0.0.1 my css files work fine. Its just whenever I post a form in my application, it redirects it to port 8080 which messes up my css

Comment: edit your post to include your nginx/apache confs it might be a setting issue

Comment: I might need to point out that it only does it when I use HttpResponseRedirect is the only time it changes it from /localhost/ to /127.0.0.1:8080/

Comment: have you seen this? It might be related to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457006/djangos-httpresponseredirect-seems-to-strip-off-my-subdomain

Comment: Thanks all! I have fixed it for now by defining ROOT_URL in the settings.py file and just using settings.ROOT_URL + '<url>' to achieve what I want. Although its gonna be a hassle to do it every time I use HttpResponseRedirect.. :( If anyone knows of a better way, let me know! LOL

Comment: An alternative to proxy_redirect is "proxy_set_header Host $host;" which causes nginx to send the original host header to the proxied server.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using VirtualHost, you need to set USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True in your settings.py

Here's the reference: [Django Doc for Settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/)

> USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST New in Django 1.3.1: Please, see the release
>   notes
>
> Default: False
>
> A boolean that specifies whether to use the X-Forwarded-Host header in
>   preference to the Host header. This should only be enabled if a proxy
>   which sets this header is in use.

Here's some example code:

```
import os, socket
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

on_production_server = True if socket.gethostname() == 'your.productionserver.com' else False

DEBUG = True if not on_production_server else False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True if not on_production_server else False
```

Comment: +1: this is the right answer for anyone whose HTTP server is configured correctly but whose Django server is not.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem (django redirects got to the browser with the ":8080" appended).  After further searching, I found some nginx info.  The following fixed it...

In your nginx config, replace...

```
  proxy_redirect    off;
```

with....

```
  proxy_redirect   http://127.0.0.1:8080/ http://127.0.0.1/;
```

Remember to restart your nginx daemon.  This causes nginx to strip the 8080 on packets flowing from apache back to the browser.  For example a redirect from django via apache, http://127.0.0.1:8080/my/test/file.html will become http://127.0.0.1/my/test/file.html after nginx sends it back to the client.

Now you won't have to modify your django code.