# https://example.com/admin redirects to https://admin in Django Nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, https, nginx, gunicorn

The entire application works with Django + Nginx + Gunicorn using SSL(in production). But when I try to access django-admin page by https://example.com/admin and try to login it redirects me to (https://admin).

PS: Sorry for a silly question. Any inputs ?

Comment: Show nginx and unicorn configs.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very similar to [Django's HttpResponseRedirect seems to strip off my subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1457006/647002).

And if so, the likely issue is that either your nginx proxy or Gunicorn is not delivering the domain name (HTTP_HOST) to Django. Verify by examining request.META within Django.